# using a for loop to create a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe, unique

I have a list of 26 data frames. I'm using the code below to create a vector. Is there a way I can use the for loop to apply the same unique function on all the 26 data frames and have a new list of 26 data frames with the vector in each data frame? Each data frame would create a different vector depending on that data frame.

```
(unique(paste(list[[1]]$row, list[[1]]$col, sep=""))

> (unique(paste(list[[1]]$row, list[[1]]$col, sep="")))
 [1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8"  "B9" 
[21] "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4"  "D5" 
[41] "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9"  "E10" "E11" "E12" "F1" 
[61] "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9" 
[81] "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"
```

So the result I want is something like...

```
[[1]]
[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8"  "B9" 
[21] "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4"  "D5" 
[41] "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9"  "E10" "E11" "E12" "F1" 
[61] "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9" 
[81] "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

[[2]]
[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8"  "B9" 
[21] "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4"  "D5" 
[41] "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9"  "E10" "E11" "E12" "F1" 
[61] "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9" 
[81] "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

[[3]] 
[1] "E10" "E11" "E12" "F1"  "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5" 
[21] "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9"  "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

etc etc until [[26]]
```

**Clarification**

Each data frame contains any or all of the elements that the following list contains (the following list has 96 elements):

```
list(c(paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:8], each=12), rep(1:12, 8))))
```

So I need something that would go through my list of 26 data frames and tell me the elements that each data frame contains. Because some of the data frames may not have all 96 elements, I showed that [[3]] in my example of result I want only has only like.. 40 elements. Hope that's more clear now..

Comment: Use `lapply`. It's designed for such tasks.

Comment: @Roland so something like this? lapply(list, function(x) unique(paste(list[[i]]$row, list[[i]]$col, sep=""))) It's giving me data frames of the list now but the vector that it's returning does not correspond with each data frame of the original list.

Comment: Almost. `lapply(list, function(x) unique(paste0(x$row, x$col)))`

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
lapply(list, function(x) unique(do.call(paste0, x)))
```

should do it.  `do.call` calls its first argument (in this case the function `paste0`) with the arguments set to `do.call`'s second argument.  Since `x` is a data frame, which is a list, this works nicely.  Here is the sample output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "G18" "J20" "N12" "U11" "E1" 

[[2]]
[1] "F10" "E14" "Q18" "I7"  "X13"

[[3]]
[1] "Y8"  "F1"  "P7"  "C15" "Z6" 

[[4]]
[1] "M14" "O16" "L2"  "E13" "S7" 

[[5]]
[1] "V16" "Q1"  "S9"  "M13" "L12"
```

And the data I used:

```
set.seed(1)
list <- replicate(5, data.frame(row=sample(LETTERS, 5), col=sample(1:20, 5)), s=F)
lapply(list, function(x) do.call(paste0, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the structure of your data, so please pardon my fake data sets.

You can also use `transform` within the `lapply` function.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3),
                  b = c(4, 5, 6))

df2 <- data.frame(a = c(5, 6, 7),
                  b = c(8, 9, 10))

dfList <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2)

lapply(dfList, transform, c = a - b)
```